# Grid view column accept only decimal?

Tags: winforms, telerik, radgrid

i am Using Telerik controls (GridView) i wanna to set A specific column only accept numbers with one decimal point

Answer (score 0):

You can follow two different approaches:

1) Use data [validation](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-editors-data-validation.html) and therefore give a warning to the user that the typed format is not the desired one.

2) Define the [formatting](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-columns-gridviewdecimalcolumn.html) of your column and get visualized the rounded result.

```
GridViewDecimalColumn decimalColumn = new GridViewDecimalColumn();
decimalColumn.Name = "DecimalColumn";
decimalColumn.HeaderText = "Unit Price";
decimalColumn.FieldName = "UnitPrice";
decimalColumn.DecimalPlaces = 1;
radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Columns.Add(decimalColumn);
```